# how to use loadItemForTypeIdentifier to load an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, phpickerviewcontroller, nsitemprovider

I have the following function which loads an image using the new `PHPickerViewController`:

```
- (void) picker:(PHPickerViewController *)picker didFinishPicking:(NSArray<PHPickerResult *> *)results
{
    PHPickerResult *result = [results firstObject];
    
    if (result)
    {
       [result.itemProvider loadObjectOfClass:[UIImage class] completionHandler:^(__kindof id<NSItemProviderReading>  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error)
       {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            ^{
                if (!error)
                {
                    [self pickerControllerDidFinishPickingWithImage:(UIImage *)object];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self pickerControllerDidFinishWithError];
                }
            });
       }];
    }
}
```

I want to avoid using `loadObjectOfClass` because I don't want the image to load asynchronously. So I opted to use `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` instead and did the following:

```
   [result.itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.image" options:nil completionHandler:^(__kindof id<NSItemProviderReading>  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error)
   {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            if (!error)
            {
                [self pickerControllerDidFinishPickingWithImage:(UIImage *)object];
            }
            else
            {
                [self pickerControllerDidFinishWithError];
            }
        });
   }];
```

However, when I run this code I am getting:

> ncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL
> imageOrientation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x600001ce5920' terminating with uncaught exception of type
> NSException

I am not that great with blocks and this is my first time using a `UTI` so I'm wondering, what am I doing wrong here? Is it even possible to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish, i.e. pull a `UIImage` out using `loadItemForTypeIdentifier`? Am I getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: The error you get is because you receive a `NSURL` object, not `UIImage`. I don't really get your reason to use the loadItemForTypeIdentifier, you said you didn't want the image to load asynchronously but according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider/1403900-loaditemfortypeidentifier) it does load asynchronously: _If the item provider object is able to provide data in the requested type, it does so and asynchronously executes your completionHandler block with the results. The block may be executed on a background thread._

Comment: @ScorpiCon Yeah you're absolutely right, in the function descriptions on the NSItemProvider documentation page, it mentioned all the other functions as being asynchronous but not loadItemForTypeIdentifier that's why I assumed. But when you go to the loadItemForTypeIdentifier page, it does indeed say that.